# Cloning and Deleting a channel: Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```py
@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def nuke(ctx, channel_name):
    existing_channel = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name=channel_name)
    if existing_channel is not None:
        await clone(name=channel_name,reason="Has been nuked")
        await existing_channel.delete()
    else:
        await ctx.send(f'No channel named **{channel_name}** was found')
```

I've seen multiple bots on discord that can already do this, via a nuke command, but I wanted to learn how to do this myself. The problem is, my bot is unable to detect that I've mentioned a channel (as seen in the attached image). I found a question similar to this about 'nuking a channel properly' but they were using cogs. Help? [This is the attached picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Emyzh.png)

Comment: Hi. What are you trying to pass as `channel_name`? When you tag a channel #example-channel and it is a clickable link to that channel, it actually uses channel ID and will be <#channel_id>. which your search will not find. you will have to type `nuke example-channel` for your search to find anything

Comment: The problem I had was that no matter what I typed I still wouldn't get an error message  I have tried to use `nuke example-channel` but it still didn't work in the end. Is there a way for the bot to use the clickable #example-channel instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `clone()` wrong, its `Channel.clone()` not only `clone()`

Below is the revised code

```py
@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def nuke(ctx, channel_name):
    existing_channel = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name=channel_name)
    if existing_channel is not None:
        await existing_channel.clone(reason="Has been nuked")
        await existing_channel.delete()
    else:
        await ctx.send(f'No channel named **{channel_name}** was found')
```

Comment: I have found that this does clone the channel, but does not delete the channel. I'll see if there's any reason behind this in the mean time.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun already pointed out that you have been using the wrong command to clone.
I'm using their code, but putting in the change where you wanted the channel name to be the clickable #example-channel.

When tagging a channel, the bot sees: `<#123456789>`, not `#example-channel`. We need only the numbers so we can get the channel ID. The first two lines of the code.

```
@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def nuke(ctx, channel_name):
    channel_id = int(''.join(i for i in channel_name if i.isdigit())) 
    existing_channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    if existing_channel:
        await existing_channel.clone(reason="Has been nuked")
        await existing_channel.delete()
    else:
        await ctx.send(f'No channel named **{channel_name}** was found')
```

A good idea when trying to debug is to `print()` the different objects so you can see what they are.

`print(channel_name)` will show you what the bot sees when you tag. You might be able to see from that why it's not finding any 'channel name'.

Comment: `if existing_channel is not None:` can be shortened to just `if existing_channel:`

Comment: @kr8gz True! Thanks for pointing that out. changing it in the code now.